# componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidUpdate infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update the state after changing state from a child component and without success, every time I call the function I got a stack overflow, the prop is calling infinite times the function, but the question is, I really need to update this state and have no idea how to solve this currently.

**Parent**

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import Card from './card/card.js';
import style from './style.scss';

class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFlipped: false,
      oneOpened: true,
      history: [],
      childFlipToFalse: false,
    };
    this.historyToggleStates = this.historyToggleStates.bind(this);
    this.forceFlipParent = this.forceFlipParent.bind(this);
    this.checkForceFlip = false;
  }
  historyToggleStates(bool, id, callForceFlip) {
    this.setState({
      history: this.state.history.concat([{ opened: bool, id }]),
    }, () => {
      console.log('inside historyToggleStates');
      if (callForceFlip) {
        this.forceFlipParent()
      }
    });
  }
  forceFlipParent() {
    const { history } = this.state;
    const first = history[0];
    const last = history[history.length - 1];
    const beforeLast = history[history.length - 2];
    console.log('force FLIP PARENT');
    if (history.length > 1) {
      if (JSON.stringify(last.opened) === JSON.stringify(beforeLast.opened)) {
        this.setState({ childFlipToFalse: true });
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    const rest = {
      basePath: this.props.basePath,
      backCard: this.props.backCard,
      isShowing: this.props.isShowing,
      historyToggleStates: this.historyToggleStates,
      isOpened: this.state.isOpened,
      isFlipped: this.state.isFlipped,
      checkOneOpened: this.checkOneOpened,
      history: this.state.history,
      forceFlip: this.state.childFlipToFalse,
      flipToFalse: this.forceFlipParent,

    };
    const cardsMap = this.props.cards.map((item, key) => {
      return (
        <Card
          item={item}
          keyId={key}
          {...rest}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12 text-center">
        {cardsMap}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Container;

Container.propTypes = {
  cards: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  item: PropTypes.func,
  basePath: PropTypes.string,
  backCard: PropTypes.string,
  isShowing: PropTypes.bool,
};
```

**Child**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactCardFlip from 'react-card-flip';
import style from './style.scss';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFlipped: false,
      update: false,
      id: 9999999,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.checkOneOpened = this.checkOneOpened.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
    const { history, isFlipped, historyToggleStates } = this.props;
    const last = nextprops.history[nextprops.history.length - 1];
    const beforeLast = nextprops.history[nextprops.history.length - 2];
    console.log(history);
    console.log(nextprops.history);
    if (nextprops.forceFlip && last.id === nextprops.keyId) {
      this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped, update: true, id: last.id }, () => {
        console.log('callback willreceiveprops', this.state.isFlipped);
        historyToggleStates(this.state.isFlipped, nextprops.keyId, true, this.state.update);  **<--- Here's my problem**
      });
    }
    if (nextprops.forceFlip && beforeLast.id === nextprops.keyId) {
      this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped, update: true, id: beforeLast.id }, () => {
      });
    }
  }

  handleClick(e, nextState, id) {
    const { keyId, historyToggleStates, forceFlip } = this.props;
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (!nextState) {
      this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped }, () => {
        historyToggleStates(this.state.isFlipped, keyId, true, this.state.update);
      });
    } else {
      // historyToggleStates(nextState, id, false);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  checkOneOpened(e) {
    if (!this.props.isShowing) {
      this.handleClick(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { item, basePath, backCard, isShowing, isFlipped, forceFlip } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={`col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 ${style.card}`}>
        <ReactCardFlip
          isFlipped={this.state.isFlipped}
          flipSpeedBackToFront={0.9}
          flipSpeedFrontToBack={0.9}
        >
          <div key="front">
            <button
              onClick={() => {this.checkOneOpened()}}
            >
              <img src={isShowing ? `${basePath}${item.image}` : backCard} alt={item.name} className={`${style.img}`} />
            </button>
          </div>
          <div key="back">
            <button
              onClick={() => {this.checkOneOpened()}}
            >
              <img src={isShowing ? backCard : `${basePath}${item.image}`} alt={item.name} className={`${style.img}`} />
            </button>
          </div>
        </ReactCardFlip>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;


Card.propTypes = {
  basePath: PropTypes.string,
  backCard: PropTypes.string,
  isShowing: PropTypes.bool,
  historyToggleStates: PropTypes.func,
  isOpened: PropTypes.bool,
  isFlipped: PropTypes.bool,
  checkOneOpened: PropTypes.func,
};
```

historyToggleStates(this.state.isFlipped, nextprops.keyId, true, this.state.update) is the root of my issue, and I really need to update this because I'm comparing the array inside him with another array

**Update 1:** I know that my calling to *historyToggleStates* is being done in the couple cases, but as you can see I need to update my state from the parent because I compare this value every time in my componentWillReceiprops from my child component.

Is it really necessary a state manager for this situation? I'm following the tips from [Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367), and avoiding raise the complexity of the system, any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child component's `componentWillReceiveProps`, which in the first place is triggered when it is updated by the parent with new props, trigger's an update in the parent (with `historyToggleStates`).

However for this cycle depends on the following:

```
if (nextprops.forceFlip && last.id === nextprops.keyId) {
```

i.e. if component's incoming prop's `keyId` is same as last component in the history's `keyId`. In other words, when the children get updated, the last component in the history will always run this code block provided `forceFlip` is true.

`forceFlip`'s value depends on the following:

```
    if (history.length > 1) {
       if (JSON.stringify(last.opened) === JSON.stringify(beforeLast.opened)) {
```

i.e. `forceFlip` is set to true if any last two components in the history are simultaneously open.

Then, as you said `historyToggleStates` is triggered, parent gets updated, child's `componentWillReceiveProps` gets triggered and the cycle repeats.

**Possible Workaround**

Now I take it that it was intentionally designed that if last two cards were simultaneously open, they must be force flipped i.e. closed.

To achieve this, I'd say don't keep the state of the card localised in the card component, but pull it up to the parents components state and keep the children card components agnostic. In the parent, maintain something like `cardsState` (maybe a better name) and use it to decide whether a card must be open or not. You can close the last two simultaneously open cards by simply setting their state to false if you detect that they are open in the history.

This will free you from the dependency on `forceFlip` variable and will keep you children card component simpler - open them only if the state says open.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I'll try to refactor the states managements based on this and if it helps me achieve my result mark as correct answer.

Comment: @YuriRamos Were you able lift the state up?

Comment: Very Grateful for your approach! Sorry by the late, I was in a hurry last week. But I've already marked as the correct answer, with your approach I've made it work. The weirdness is that I already tried an approach like that, but I was so tired that didn't make it right. Btw, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

your calling **historyToggleStates** in both case with **callForceFlip** as true, which causes **forceFlipParent** on the parent to be invoked which sets **childFlipToFalse** to **True** (passed to the child as **forceFlip**)

i believe **forceFlip** being always true is the source of your problem.

Comment: This is not true entirely. If you run the code you'll see that you'll be able to flip the cards and doesn't immediately run into infinite loop. The issue is seen if more we try to open more than one card (without closing the last one). If what you say were true the code be in infinite loop from the get go.

Comment: if you see the initial state of the child u'll see the update property initialized with false, the concerned code is in componentWillReceiveProps (which is not invoked on the first render). meaning the second his component receives new props it will enter in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue similar to this where my handleClick was looping infinitely, try this for your onClick function:

```
onClick={() => {this.checkOneOpened()}}
```

Comment: That's a nice tip, I always forgot to declare as arrow function, but still don't work, I think it's something related to my lifecycles.

Comment: @YuriRamos worth a try :) is this line of code looping? console.log('force FLIP PARENT');

Comment: No, my problem is with this line `historyToggleStates(this.state.isFlipped, nextprops.keyId, true, this.state.update);`

Comment: Using es6 arrow functions in your render methid is very bad practice. It breaks `PureComponent` shallow compare and causes increased work for the garbage collector. It also adds the overhead of function definition within every render per use.

Answer (score 1):

- I thinks the problem is in this part

  ```
  if (nextprops.forceFlip && last.id === nextprops.keyId) {
   this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped, update: true, id: last.id }, () => {
   console.log('callback willreceiveprops', this.state.isFlipped);
   historyToggleStates(this.state.isFlipped, nextprops.keyId, true, this.state.update); // **<--- Heres my problem**
  });}
  ```

  you can check the values of the `if` condition so after the re-rendered it not going inside condition.
- The `prop-types` have move to a different package, check out so you don't get a warning for that https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html
- Suggest to change that name property of `childFlipToFalse` to `ischildFlip`
- Here you can take out the call back function as you are not use it

  ```
  this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped, update: true, id: beforeLast.id }, () => {});
  ```

  to

  ```
  this.setState({ isFlipped: !this.state.isFlipped, update: true, id: beforeLast.id });
  ```

This is my suggestion: In this case you can make the parent component the only class Componente and the children a staless component this will help have a better structure and manage your child component, this will make you do a different work around of the case that will be more easy to approach